# Align form and buttons inside div

Tags: html, css, forms

I tried adding `container` and/or `row` div classes and also tried to add left position for all. How can I align these elements in a row with no `css` or minimal `css` changes ?

```
   <div class="container">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
        <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button">Stop - X</button>
      </span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control">
      <form method="post" action="/controller/new" class="button_to">
          <input value="New" type="submit" />
      </form>
  </div>
```

I am expecting to have [Go][Stop][ ....  ][Submit] in same row. Link for the demo [repl](https://repl.it/NSjs/4)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to add this piece of css:

```
form { 
    display: inline;
}
```

`<form>` - is a [block level](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements) element, so it breaks lines before and after itself. You have to make it behave as if it is an inline element to overcome the issue.

```css
form {
    display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
        <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button">Stop - X</button>
      </span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control">
      <form method="post" action="/controller/new" class="button_to">
          <input value="New" type="submit" />
      </form>
  </div>
```

Comment: @curvedball: perfect

Comment: you may consider adding a full snippet code for a more complete answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your form is set to display: block; change it to display: inline-block; and it will work like charm.

```css
form{
display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
        <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button">Stop - X</button>
      </span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control">
      <form method="post" action="/controller/new" class="button_to">
          <input value="New" type="submit" />
      </form>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `display: inline-block` to your form (.button_to):

```
.button_to {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

You can also remove that styles with `position: left` because it's unnecessary.